# Include not loading navigational entities EF 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have ran into an issue where .Include does not loads the navigational entities of an Entity using EF 6. Here is my code

```
 var fields = db.GroupFields.OrderBy(a=>a.Field.DisplayOrder)
                .Where(a => groupIds.Contains(a.GroupId)
                       && a.IsActive == true
                       && a.Group.IsActive)
                .Include(a => a.Field)
                .Include(a => a.Field.Datasource) 
     .Include(a=>a.Field.Datasource.MasterItems).Select(a=>a.Field).ToList();
```

The problem with this is it is not loading the **DataSource** and the **DataSource.MasterItems** on the select query which are properties of the Entity **Field**. 
What am I doing wrong in this.

Comment: The query looks fine to me; I suspect the issue lies somewhere in your relationship mappings. The easiest way to tell would be to post a comparison of the SQL you are generating vs working SQL which retrieves the data.

Comment: I have achieved the end result by using this

    **db.GroupFields
                           .Include(a => a.Field)
                           .Include(a => a.Field.Datasource)
                           .Include(a => a.Field.Datasource.MasterItems)
                           .Where(a => groupIds.Contains(a.GroupId)
                                    && a.IsActive == true
                                    && a.Group.IsActive).ToList()
                           .Select(a => a.Field).ToList();**

Comment: What I cannot understand is I need .ToList() before selecting actual Entity(**Field**)

Comment: You shouldn't need to -- Entity Framework won't make the call to the DB until the first time the returned IQueryable is enumerated, and you're forcing it with ToList(). You should get the same result if you just loop through it without calling ToList().

Comment: Yeah that's my point also. Since the expression looks valid to me. and all of the navigational properties are proper (data annotation). and upon evaluation, it loads the data properly, but when i try to Select(a=>a.Field).ToList() that wheres the problem lies.